# "User cannot suggest edits to this question"

Tags: support

Lately, I've been into edits using my new self phone, and all went smoothly.

But today, when I tried to suggest an edit to a new question, I simply couldn't.

Instead, I got this message: 
"User cannot suggest edits to this question".

Here is a screenshot, in case that helps.

[image: user cannot suggest edits to this askubuntu question]

As you can see, the message tells me that I can't, but it doesn't give me the reason why.

What I did (or didn't) to make the system reject my suggestion?

Is it a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because while you are in the middle of making your edit, somebody else submits an edit that is still pending approval by users with at least 2000 reputation.

Comment: And it is disallowed to suggest edits on meta posts :)